# non network based dos attack

Tags: denial-of-service, websecurity

I noticed that most dos attacks basically exhaust the bandwidth. So is there any ***DOS*** attack can shut down the target's server without exhausting target's network resources?

Answer (score 0):

That kind of attack is based on vulnerabilities in the server implementation.

One of the awesome ones is [Slowloris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security)), which [attacks the single-connection-per-thread design of Apache](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiFkyR35v2Y).